# Remove brackets which exists in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do have an array which looks like:

```
["[0, 1]", "0", "1"]
```

The question is how to remove brackets inside the array, so the result which I wish to get would be:

```
["0", "1", "0", "1"]
```

Currently, I'm out of idea...

Comment: Did you try anything? Please update with some attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
["[0, 1]", "0", "1"].to_s.split(/\W/).reject(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specific structure of the array elements, you might be able to [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) the elements for things that look like numbers and then use [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) to unroll the arrays you get from `scan`:

```
['[0, 1]', '0', '1'].flat_map { |e| e.scan(/\d+/) }
# ["0", "1", "0", "1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array elements might be nested, then I would go straight to `YAML` or `JSON` parsers:

```
require 'json'
['[0, [1, 0], 1]', '0', '1'].flat_map { |s| JSON.parse(s) }

# => [0, [1, 0], 1, 0, 1]
```